# How to access the array object of audios with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to play a array of audio with duration. I saw some posts that the Object has no length so I decide to use Object.keys instead of for loop. But I got some error 'Cannot convert undefined or null to object' and 'sound/undefined.wav 404 (Not Found)' and 'Failed to load because no supported source was found.'. Where did I do wrong? Appreciate any helps.

```
<button id="subBut" style=display:none onClick="">Start!!</button>
<div id="audioControl">
    <button id="play" style=display:none onClick="">Play!!</button>
    <button id="pause" style=display:none onClick="">Pause!!</button>
    <br>
    <div id="counDownTimer" style=dispaly:none></div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#enterVariables").on("click", function() {
        $('#enterVariables').hide();
        startBut.show();
        $("#pause").hide();
    });
</button>

var playList = [{"duration": 5000, "value": "0_silence"},{"duration":5000, "value": "1_hello"}, {"duration": 5000, "value": "2_how_old"}];
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#play").on("click", function(){

                    playAudio(playList);
                    function playAudio(playList) {
                        playNextNote(playList);
                        function playNextNote(playList) {
                                var i = 0;

                                var playListKeys = Object.keys(playList);
                                if (i < playListKeys.length) {
                                //for (i in playList){
                                        var value = playListKeys[i].value;

                                        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
                                        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound/'+ value + '.wav');

                                        audioElement.play();
                                        i++;
                                        setTimeout(playNextNote, playListKeys.duration);
                                    }
                            }
                        };
                    });
 });
```

Comment: playList is an array (of objects), not an object itself, so Object.keys(playList) won't work.

Comment: You need to show the HTML

Comment: @James But I declare the playList as an object of array and then I convert it normal array, right? If not, how should I fix it?

Comment: @ScottMarcus My HTML5 has nothing. Please see the update.

Comment: playListKeys  is an array of keys, Obj = playList[playListKeys[i]], then Obj.value would work. You iterate i to get all the objects in array

Comment: @Popeye I follow your suggestion to do the Obj = playList[playListKeys[i], and I try to print, it works but I still got error 'Cannot convert undefined or null to object', '56735/sound/undefined.wav 404 (Not Found)', and 'Failed to load because no supported source was found.' Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: Obj is just a variable. Also make sure that playList isn't empty.

Comment: My playList isn't empty. But I still got error...

Answer (score 0):

A few possible problems with your code:

- as mentioned playList is an array, so just iterate it like you would
  any array.
- you set i to zero every time playNextNote is called so it will never get past the first entry in the array.  Also, the i variable needs to
  be global in scope so when setTimeout resolves it can be accessed.
- the function playAudio is defined within another function, so when setTimeout resolves it won't know what playAudio is (out of scope)
- playAudio seems to be a pointless wrapper for playNextNote, so I removed it.

Here are the fixes

```js
var playList = [{"duration": 5000, "value": "0_silence"},{"duration":5000, "value": "1_hello"}, {"duration": 5000, "value": "2_how_old"}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#play").on("click", function(){
    playNextNote(playList);
  });
});

var i = 0;

function playNextNote(playList) {
  if (i < playList.length) {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound/'+ playList[i].value + '.wav');
    audioElement.play();
    setTimeout(playNextNote, playList[i].duration);
    i++;    
  } else {
    i = 0; // reset i to zero to start over if button clicked again
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying James. I did what you suggested but I still got an error, 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined', which I think because my playList is not an array, it's an array of objects. That's why I need to convert it to Object.keys(playList) , right?

Comment: An array of objects is an array.  An array of elephants is an array.  You absolutely don't need Object.keys at all.  Make sure the sample that you have posted as your array actually is your array, though.  By the error message it sounds like it isn't.

Comment: I think my array is actually an array because I tried to console.log to my playList[0].value, it shows 0_silence. Sorry, I might not understand what you mean. I still got 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'' error. Would you mind editing again?

Comment: The "length of undefined" error (assuming this occurs on `if (i < playList.length)`) is indicating that playList is undefined.  Make sure you are passing the correct parameter to the playNextNote function!

Comment: I think I found out where I got it wrong. I was dumb. You don't need to pass the param again for your, function playNextNote(playList), because the one above has been passed once.